# three variables Exponential diophantine

Tags: number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many integers $x$, $y$ and $z$ satisfying the equality

$x^x\times y^y = z^z$

i'm sorry but i have no idea about how to start.

Comment: What happens when one of $\{x,y,z\}$ is equal to one?

Comment: i'm sorry but i forgot to mention that $x$ $y$ and $z$ are $>1$

Comment: All greater than one huh. Hmmm.

Comment: Yes Amcalde :-)

Comment: weird, i can't even find an example of such a triple :-s

Comment: Where did you encounter this problem?

Comment: a pdf paper on the internet, i'll try to find it and post it later, i've been told that this problem is from some book called "diophantine equations"

Comment: WLOG: take $x<y$. It seems that $y<z<x+y$ for some reason I can't prove. ($z<2y$ is easy to prove). Also if you think about the prime decomposition you can prove a few, perhaps useful, things. Using these insights I've found some numbers that come close, but not any actual such triples.

e.g. $\{14700,3176523000000,3176523004900\}$ comes very close, but no cigar.

Comment: Hi , it's exercise 23 >> http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/Maths/Courseware/NumberTheory/Exercises-1.pdf 
Good luck and thank you !